# AngularJS special scope arrangement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have an interesting situation. I have an angularJS app broken into several different modules. This is done so the different pieces can be as generic as possible and eventually reused. One of these modules is a uiTemplate module which handles very common tasks dealing with the ui such as expandable/collapsible sections. Is it possible to place other modules "below" the uitemplate module so that when they emit events they pass through the uitemplate? The goal is to be able to do this without the uitemplate module knowing anything about the other modules, or in other words, without the uitemplate having any "hardcoded" dependencies on the other modules. If I could dynamically tell uitemplate its dependencies that would be ok, I would just like to avoid putting application-specific code into the module. Possible ideas?

Comment: You may be thinking of nested controllers. You can have a "parent" controller that handles $scope.$broadcast events down to child controllers.  The children can $scope.$emit up to the parent controller. The important part to remember is that the child and parent controllers do not share $scope.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but my question is how do i make other modules children of the uitemplate module without declaring the modules like this: var uiTemplateModule = angular.module('uitemplate', ['translation', 'ui', 'uiComponents']);

Comment: Pretty much you just nest the DOM elements. Code in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to avoid though... Is it possible to compile a directive from uitemplate then use that scope to compile the main directive from other modules and just append it to uitemplate?

Comment: Directives get compiled differently than controllers. So long as they're included in the main app, you can call them from anywhere. You can nest directives as well, to share scope.

Comment: So I have an appDirective (app module), uiDirective (uitemplate module) and testDirective (test module). The app module knows about all other modules. the uitemplate module knows nothing about the other modules. If I am in appDirective, how can I compile the directives to get a scope hierarchy that looks like this:
appDirective (parent)
    uiDirective (child of appDirective)
        testDirective (child of uiDirective)

Comment: http://www.egghead.io/video/rzMrBIVuxgM explains it a lot better than I would.

Comment: I might be able to work with this if it works cross-module. Does it?

Comment: Alright I'll mess with it for a few hours lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="Child1Ctrl"></div>
    <div ng-controller="Child2Ctrl"></div>
</div>
```

However, if you're talking about sharing just UI elements, it might make more sense to make them directives. They get compiled differently and you can call them from any view.